# Increment counter without it getting reset

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming. I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this.
I have a class which looks like this:

```
public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException {
  try {
    if (stuff) {
      j++;
    }
    if (j = 10) {
      -do other stuff-
    }
}
```

I want to increment `j`, but I can't initialise it to 0 within the `try{}` structure, otherwise it will be reset every time. Can I `init` it to 0 just before that, without it being reset to 0 every time?

Comment: where is j defined right now?

Comment: just make it a global variable and initialize it there

Answer (score 0):

What is the real problem? What you posted here is called a method/function not a `class`. Why can't you make `j` a field in your class, so it will be 'visible' to your method? Then you don't need to initialize it every time you run your method.